# CACert add domain

Tags: email, redirect, ssl, server

I've registered at CACert to get a trusted certificate for my domain example.com, when I want to add the domain in the CACert control panel I have to select a email adress that is used for this domain: [image]

The CACert FAQ states that there is currently no other way than getting an email at one of the specified email accounts. I currently don't have an email server running on my server to receive that email, but I tried to run one and it didn't work. Of course I could have read the documentations for the email server and try to get the server working, but is there a simpler way of receiving that email, because I just need that one email and it would be a realy big effort to run a full email server for this? Can I maybe redirect a email that is send at admin@example.com to my email adress at yahoo? With OS I'm flexible, I can use Windows or Linux, I just want to know the easiest way of receiving that adress.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't another way of verfifying. But you easily setup an smtp server with postfix to receive the email